# SQL вывести все строки где общий COUNT >1

Tags: sql

Есть такая таблица:

```
PeopleID | Name   | Father | Mother
-----------------------------------
1        | Vasia  | null   | null
2        | Sveta  | 4      | 3
3        | Lena   | null   | null
4        | Andrey | null   | null
5        | Kostik | 1      | 6
6        | Olga   | 4      | 3
6        | Victoria| null  | null
```

Мне нужно вывести семьи, в которых 2 и более ребенка.
Получается, что У Андрея с Леной 2 ребенка - Света и Ольга, а у Васи с Викторией - один, Костик.

Пока что, я пытаюсь, хотя бы, вывести только детей где COUNT>1 по столбцу Father, но у меня выводит только последнего, а не всех.

```
SELECT F1.FullName, COUNT(F1.Father) AS value_occurrence
FROM FAMILY F1
GROUP BY F1.Father
HAVING
    COUNT(F1.Father) > 1
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC;
```

Comment: `group by Father, Mother`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выведет имя отца, матери и количество детей:

```
SELECT C1.name, C2.name, count(C0.name) FROM family C0,family C1,family C2
WHERE C1.PeopleID = C0.father AND C2.PeopleID = C0.Mother
GROUP BY C1.name, C2.name
--HAIVING COUNT(C0.name) > 1 /*Убрать комментарий строки '--' если нужно только больше 1 ребенка*/
```

Answer (score 0):

группируй по колонке `PeopleID`

```sql
GROUP BY `PeopleID`
```

Группировка сокращает количество выводимых записей по указанному полю до 1-го

Comment: колонку id точно добавлять не надо и группировать по ней тем более. группировка по уникальной колонке заведомо бесполезна

Comment: тогда использовать `inner join`